# jQuery - Adding event to future elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out a way to delegate an event to future, dynamically loaded elements using .on

I have a button (#button) which is present when the DOM is loaded.

The new elements (let's give them a class of .newElement) are then loaded into the page dynamically.

I want to click on '#button' and scroll to '.newElement.'

Is this possible?

The following is where my head is at:

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", '#button', function (e) {
            jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('.newElement').offset().top);
        });
```

This doesn't work as #button can't find .newElement in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: I was going to dupe close this in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements, however it doesn't seem like it's a fit. You don't need to use event binding on #button, which is what you're doing. Please post a [mcve], specifally related to how `.newElement` is being added.

Comment: You can't scroll to something that isn't there? When the element is inserted, getting the offset and scrolling to it should work the way you're doing it ?

Comment: Have the elements that have class `.newElement` been added prior to clicking the button?  You should show a full working example so we can determine what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this one.

```
jQuery("body").on("click", '#button', function (e) {
            jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('.newElement').offset().top);
        });
```

Comment: This just changes which element has the click handler, changing that does not affect wither or not jQuery will find an element with `newElement` class

Comment: Let me know if this helps. 

Create a fiddle for you for better understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/o11ouj2e/4/